# Where should the GWT dialog title be set?

Tags: gwt, dialog

GWT dialog on demo app has a title (or caption) of "Remote Procedure Call". Can I set this somewhere, if so, where?

...or do I have to use a subclass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use 'text' property of DialogBox if you don't want to use a Subclass.

```
dialogBox.setText("Text");
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was being dumb, the DialogBox Text was being set in the onSuccess method of the handler so all my hard work to set it in the onModuleLoad was being undone.